Blender 4.2 cannot install addons anymore
There is no more “install plugin” button

I tried creating a repository pointing to a folder full of addons, they don’t show up

I tried creating a local folder repository, the repository does not point to the dir I selected, if I go to advanced and try to reselect the proper directory, blender crashes

I found I had to create the local repo, quit blender, as I launch blender, my local repo is there, but none of the plugin I have in that directory are showing up.



See if this post in the Blender Developer Forum helps.

In Edit->Preferences->Add-ons, in the upper right corner there is an "open dropdown" button:

If you click on that, it gives you the same options that were visible in that corner in earlier versions of Blender.
Install from Disk works just like the old Install did.
I don't know anything about repositories. I just have a folder with my third-party addons in it and install them the same way as in earlier versions of Blender.

but from the doc it says it is built in, wth...

Hi. Are you looking for what you asked for in your new question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/323197/4-2-where-is-the-3d-print-addon If that is what you want, the link in the comment by @Gordon Brinkmann will show you the new way to install and activate Blender's built in addons.
